# Why does g++ (4.8.2) use c++0x as default?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, smart-pointers

I have a code which uses std::unique_ptr supported since c++11.

```
#include <memory>

int main() {
        std::unique_ptr<int> p_int(new int(3));
        return 0;
}
```

I could build this code, but I'm still confused. Becuase my g++'s version is 4.8.2 which supports c++11. What's the reason that g++ uses c++0x as default? And how should I set c++11 as default? Now I'm using cmake, so maybe I should set c++11 in CMakeLists.txt..

```
$ which g++   
/usr/bin/g++
$ g++ --version
g++ (20140812 (SCEL u2.0.0.0)) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$ g++ main.cc  
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:4:2: error: ‘unique_ptr’ is not a member of ‘std’
  std::unique_ptr<int> p_int(new int(3));
  ^
main.cc:4:18: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  std::unique_ptr<int> p_int(new int(3));
                  ^
main.cc:4:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘int’
$ g++ main.cc -std=c++11     // this is ok
```

Althoguh my question is not so critical for its building, I want to clear my thought! Any helps will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I suppose you'd need to build a custom version of `g++` to have different defaults.  Being built-in is pretty much what makes them *defaults*.

Comment: This is probably done to avoid breaking changes. Otherwise, many existing makefiles would need an upgrade.

Comment: As for *why*, the GCC suite, including `g++`, seems to  try to guess what defaults will serve the most people, the largest amount of the time.  It is normal for there to be years of lag between a new standard being introduced and `gcc` or `g++` defaulting to it.

Answer (score 5):

"*What's the reason that g++ uses c++0x as default*": [It doesn't](http://view-source:https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html). `c++0x` was the name for the working draft of `c++11`

g++ uses `-std=gnu++98` by default.  This is c++98 with GNU extensions added on top of it.  Since this has been the default for a long time, it will likely remain the default for the foreseeable future to avoid breaking code that builds with it.

If you want to use `c++11` as the default you can create an alias, in bash for example:

```
alias g++="g++ -std=c++11"
```

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I understand new specification of c++ may break existing software.